# how to access environment variables from single class as static & final constants

Tags: spring-boot, static-variables, application.properties

I had a utility file which has a list of final static constants that is being referred everywhere in the project. Now I need the constants to be referred from application.properties, since they are static i couldn't do @Value, any easier approach that has anything to do with the constants file wihtout impacting its usage areas

tried environment.getProperty("") but that has the same problem as @Value

Comment: So they aren't really static anymore, so don't access them as static, but rather inject them in other places as well. Or bind them to an properties object and inject that into the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to try this approach:

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;

private static String NAME_STATIC;

@Value("${name}")
public void setNameStatic(String name){
    PropertyController.NAME_STATIC = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class and annotate it with `@Configuration`. Set it inside static block. Then you can access your environment variables by `EnvVar.VAR_1`

```
@Configuration
public class EnvVar {

  private static final String ENV_VAR_NAME = "APP_CONTEXT";

  public static final String VAR_1;

  static {
    VAR_1 = System.getenv(ENV_VAR_NAME);
  }
}
```